# Kmeans++ (kmeans plus plus) function in R?

Tags: initialization, cluster-computing, k-means

I am clusering data with kmeans clsutering and I would like to initialize the centroids by using kmeans++. But I just cannot find a function, except for kmeanspp, which belongs to a package that is not available anymore (clusternor).
Is ther any other way to use kmeans++ in R ???

Thank you!

I tried to use kmeanspp but it just tells me this function does not exist.